# method overloading and dynamic keyword in C#

Tags: .net, dynamic, c#-4.0

I still haven't upgraded to 4.0 else I would have checked the code snippet myself.  But I hope some expert can comment on this.

In following code, will the appropriate `Print()` method be called at runtime? Is it even legal in C# 2010 to call it that way?

```
public void Test()
{
    dynamic objX = InstantiateAsStringOrDouble();

    Print(objX);
}

public void Print(string s)
{
    Console.Write("string");
}

public void Print(double n)
{
    Console.Write("double");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How would you want that to decide which Print to call? I think you'd be better off reading more about `dynamic`.

Comment: at runtime, of course. Thanks for your advice, I'm doing that already! :-)

Comment: It does work, but be careful with dynamic.  It can solve a lot of issues and simultaneously give you a lot of headaches :-) basically you gain runtime flexibility but lose all compiler time checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that does in fact work.  It will check the usage of the dynamic at runtime and call the appropriate method, however you lose almost all of your compile-time checking, so I'd make sure that's really what you'd want to do.

Comment: Thanks James. The code I'm trying to convert has 3-4 levels deep method calls with passing boxed Object parameters. I thought of writing overloaded methods but its like some if-else logic, then a method call, more if-else logic than another method call (passing the same Object parameter it gets from 2-3 levels up)....Pain in the neck sort of legacy code. Somewhere down the bottom it checks if the Object is ArrayList or HashTable or blah blah and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you can even do this:

```
public dynamic InstantiateAsStringOrDouble() { return 0.5; }
```

or

```
public dynamic InstantiateAsStringOrDouble() { return "hello"; }
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: And of course, `public dynamic ... { return true; }` will probably not work.